# What's a use case where an empty string and NULL should be treated differently?

Tags: django, oracle, null

What's an example of a scenario where an empty string and NULL should be treated as distinct values?

(I ask because Django and Oracle consider them indistinguishable, but some databases treat the empty string and NULL as 2 distinct values.)

Answer (score 1):

In short, that allows for optional unique fields.

Let's take the example of financial securities: some are identified using multiple codes. Bloomberg codes, ISIN codes, Sedol codes, Reuters codes ... But rarely would all securities have registered for all types of codes at the same time.

However if one security is already assigned one type of code, you would not want another security to reuse the same value.

Hence the need for both uniqueness and optionality, which mixing '' and NULL prevents, because the db would complain if you were trying to insert '' twice for unassigned codes.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a database table that represents an inheritance hierarchy (known as Table-Per-Hierarchy in .NET's Entity Framework). This means that a single table stores the state of all derived types in that hierarchy, as well as the base class.

Look at this class hierarchy:

```
public class Animal
{
   int Id,
   int NumberOfLegs
}

public class Cat : Animal
{
   string FurColor;
}
```

The base class Animal has no string properties. However, a derived type called Cat has a string property called FurColor. If we were using Table-Per-Hierarchy, then we would have the columns:

```
ID | NumberOfLegs | FurColor
```

We would probably also have what's called a *discriminator* column which helps differentiate between different types, but that's not important here.

Now, if you had an instance of the `Animal` base class, your object would only have 2 properties. When this object is stored into the database table, there is no value for `FurColor` because that property has nothing to do with the `Animal` class. Therefore `NULL` is the most suitable value as it indicates that there is no explicit value for this property. Empty string on the other hand could be considered to have some meaning, which is structurally incorrect for the `Animal` object, as that property is non existant on it.

If you had an instance of the `Cat` class, then your object would have 3 properties. Saving this to the database table would conceptually require all 3 fields. If `FurColor` didn't have a particular value, empty string is perfectly valid and in my opinion a better option than `NULL`. This is because when you read the object back from the database, you don't have to specifically check the property for `NULL` before using it in operations such as string concatenation (which will throw something along the lines of a NULL reference exception in most statically typed languages such as C#).

So long story short, NULL can be considered 'value-less' where an empty string might be a perfectly valid value in your application.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind these two values are semantically different. Empty string is a valid string instance while null means that the value has not been set at all (note that in general null is not reserved for string type only but is a general concept that applies to any nullable type and therefore I don't treat null as a string value (i.e. a value from the set of all possible string values) while empty string is specific to string type and is a string value - i.e. it belongs to the set of possible string values). To understand what I mean look at nullable integer type - is there a difference between 0 and null? Obviously there is. The difference between string and int example is that in real world 0 is much more useful than the empty string. In real world an empty string and null are also very often equivalents.
One use case when you may want empty string instead of null is when you want to remove all occurrences of a character/substring from a string. The easiest method is to replace what you want to remove with empty strings. I don't know what it would mean to replace a substring with a null value - it will probably behave differently depending on the language you are using. However, if I use the empty string I would expect the same behavior regardless of the language.